# Rails delete_if using hashes to ignore current article (Middleman) revisited

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman, contentful

I've got an easy one for you guys.

**I want to have a featured content section where the current article link is hidden or removed**

So already this works using Middleman Blog with `delete_if`:

```
<% blog(content).articles.delete_if{|item| item == current_article}.each do |article| %>
  <%= article.href %>
<% end %>
```

However I'm using Middleman [proxies](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/dynamic-pages/) so I don't have access to the `current_article` method...

I've got an YAML structure that holds the following mock data (amongst others) with the folder setup like: **data > site > caseStudy > RANDOM-ID423536.yaml** (Generated by a CMS)

[image]

Inside each `yaml` file you'll find stuff like:

```
:id: 2k1YccJrQsKE2siSO6o6ac
:title: Heyplace
```

My `config.rb` looks like this

```
data.site.caseStudy.each do | id, this |
  proxy "/cases/#{this.slug}/index.html", "/cases/cases-template.html", :locals => { this: this }, :ignore => true
end
```

My template file holds the following

```
<%= partial(:'partials/footer', :locals => {:content => data.site.caseStudy, :title => 'See more projects'}) %>
```

My loop that gets content

```
<% content.each do |id, this| %>
  <%= partial "partials/tile" %>
<% end %>
```

**So I guess my question is, how can I use `delete_if` in this instance so that the current article isnt being displayed?**

I have tried stuff like, but to no avail:

```
<% content.delete_if{|e| e.title == content.title}.each do |id, article| %>
  <%= article.href %>
<% end %>
```

As well as:

```
<% content.reject{|key, value| key >= this.id }.sort_by{ |index| rand }.each do |id, this| %> 
    <%= partial "partials/tile" %> 
<% end %>
```

(This deletes the data all together forever until you reload the page, strange!)

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: if it's a hash and route/url looks something like `case_studies/:id/`, you can try `content.delete_if{|_k, v| v == params[:id]}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out. My url structure is `casestudy/slug/ `. When I add the params method I get `undefined local variable or method 'params' for #<#<Class:0x007fbc13e7e790>:0x007fbc156538c0>`

Comment: I can get the ID for each article by putting `= this.id` (usually `6ezUl6lCFyO4EuEAc2eGsC`) or the slug by getting `= this.slug` (usually `the-poetry-hour`)

Comment: class? you wrote that block in model or view? it should be in view. can you share your `rake routes` if it still doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried doing `content.delete_if { |item| item == this }`? Cheers

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon It might be worth mentioning that this project is a Middleman (static site generator) project not a strictly rails setup. So I don't have a `rake routes` or anything like that

Comment: @DavidLitvak your snipped didnt do anthing, I added an `id` in the loop like so `content.delete_if{ | id, item| item == this }` and it kind of removed the tile but it also removed it entirely from the dataset so I had to restart the server. Check the gif here https://media.giphy.com/media/xUA7bjLPnUFqcFDG24/giphy.gif

Notice at the end of the gif, all my tiles were deleted from the homepage. Strange

Comment: @SebastianGraz then instead of using `delete_if` use `reject` with the same block, this will instead of deleting the item, create a new collection without that item.

Comment: Yep that did it, thanks for your help @DavidLitvak

Comment: Glad to be of help!